# Problems with cpack creating deb packages

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, debian, cpack

I set CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT and CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER in my main CMakeListst.txt. cmake itself runs an the created CPackConfig.cmake and CPackSourceConfig.cmake both contain the variables set.

CPack still exits with

CPack: Create package using DEB
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Run preinstall target for: 
CPack: - Install project: 
CPack: Create package
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CPackDeb.cmake:274 (MESSAGE):
  CPackDeb: Debian package requires a maintainer for a package, set
  CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT or CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong or how to find out what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm. "cpack --help" does not appear to document its command line options fully...

If you use "cpack -V", you'll get more verbose output. If you use "cpack --debug", you'll get a ton of output that you can wade through to try to find hints about what went wrong.

Give those a try, and see if any of the output helps you. If not, perhaps it will at least yield some more information you can post in a question edit to try to track down what the problem is.

What version of cpack are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! The --debug and -V helped me. Should really be documented!

I found the problem - I used a "," in the SET command

SET(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER, "Andreas Loew")

this does not give an error but simply leaves the variable empty...

CMake seems to copy the content of this to the CPack configuration without any change, leaving the false "," inside.

Comment: Yes... when you do that with no intervening space the "," actually becomes part of the variable name. Unfortunately CMake presently allows some crazy characters to be part of variable names.

Comment: Arg...I didn't and am getting the same crap.  -V --debug no help because it just says the same stupid thing.